# Ionic 2 - Google Maps working in browser, but not device

Tags: google-maps, ionic-framework, keystore, ionic2

I have the following implementation of Google Maps api (see link below). It works perfectly when I run ionic serve and test it in a browser. However, when I do cordova build and deploy the apk to my android 6.0.1 phone, it fails. The map does not load and it hangs on the loading spinner.

If anyone has any ideas, I would appreciate the help.

Thanks

https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/google-maps-working-in-browser-but-not-device/58819

Answer (score 3):

SOLVED:

I ran the following, and low the map loads on the device too:

> cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-geolocation

Answer (score 0):

Run the following commands:

```
ionic plugin add cordova-plugin-geolocation
```

and

```
npm install --save @ionic-native/geolocation`
```

[This link](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/google-maps-working-in-browser-but-not-device/58819) would be helpful.

Comment: Generally, answers are much more helpful if they include an explanation of what the code is intended to do, and why that solves the problem without introducing others. Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.